# compare between two pairRDD

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, key-value, rdd

I have 2 pairRdds,their tuples defined as

```
 Tuple2 <Integer,int[]>
```

what i want to do is to find tuples from both RDDs that have the same key than compare every single elements of the value part (int []) from Ra with other elements from Rb, than return  in the result_RDD Res only tuples that appears in both of rdds , same key and same values of each element of the second part (int []), giving an example, lets suppose :

```
  Ra={(1,(2,3)) (4,(9,2)) (5,(88,2)) (77,(6,1))...}
  Rb={(1,(5,5)) (4,(9,2)) (9,(22,0)) (5,(88,2))..}

  Res={(4,(9,2)) (5,(88,2))}
```

i want to return too in RESult2_RDD, tuples from Ra that appear in both of RDDs, but this time, same key and different value(means  (int []) part),

```
 RESULT2_RDD= {(1,(2,3))  ...}
```

help please....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `intersection`

```
val Res = Ra.intersection(Rb)
```

Comment: __Note:__ _intersection_ will not keep duplicates in resultant RDD.

Comment: I tried with hammad's dataset, but Res gives me an empty pairRDD, any clue how this happens?

Comment: @avr i don't need duplicates, i ll test it and see, thank u all

Comment: does it any other solution to do the same without intersection()?

Comment: @hammad That is a totally separate question. You should open a new one